# How to create a note from a chrome extension using the Evernote JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, evernote

The documentation on http://dev.evernote.com/start/core/creating_notes.php states that as a prerequisite I should "[...] have a developer token (or a working OAuth implementation by which [I] retrieve a valid authentication token". I have both of that. Check.

Next thing they assume is that "[I] have an instance of UserStore and NoteStore". This is where I'm struggling. I don't have that and I don't know how to get that.

The code example on the page I linked above is in Python and Objective-C which is not really helpful in my case.

I am using the Evernote JavaScript SDK (https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js), to be exact the `evernote-sdk-minified.js`, but I still can't figure out how to use the Evernote Cloud API (http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/) to create a note from my extension.

I tried something like

```
var user = UserStore.getUser(auth_token);
```

but that doesn't seem to work

If anyone had the same problem and would post some sample code on how to get an instance of UserStore and NoteStore which, supposedly, I need to create a note and maybe even how to create the note itself, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Evernote doesn't allow client side Javascript access to its API due to cross-site scripting concerns.

To use the the Evernote Javascript SDK you will need to [use PhoneGap](https://github.com/evernote/phonegap-example) like mentioned in another answer, [node.js and the Evernote node module](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js) (available [via npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/evernote)) or [Apache Cordova](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/start/javascript.php).

There is also a unofficial node module that can be used to access the Evernote API called [Zookeeper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/evernote-zookeeper).

Answer (score 0):

The PhoneGap example has some sample code [here](https://github.com/evernote/phonegap-example/blob/master/HelloWorld/www/js/index.js). You need to create a NoteStore client and call the [createNote](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_createNote) API.